# Hong Kong to Japan by sea

Tags: budget, japan, hong-kong, sea-travel

I want to travel to Japan from Hong Kong on a budget, so I thought maybe by sea. Are there any ferries or tour operators? By air is also fine but so far looks quite pricey... or maybe I'm looking at the wrong airlines (over US$700 for a round trip).

I would highly appreciate if anyone could advise me on this.

Comment: When you say 700$, it is HKD or USD?

Comment: A brief check of exchange rates would show which dollar he is using.

Comment: I edited to make it clear that it is US$ as HK$ makes no sense (HK$700 is around US$70). I hope this what the OP intended.

Answer (score 6):

No ferries, much too far. Best you could do is a cruise ship, but the only ones that tend to do HK - Yokohama are the ultra-luxury ocean liners like the Queen Elizabeth, and then only once a year.

If you have a lot of time there are some cargo lines that accept passengers. Cargo ship schedules are *very* flexible, you have to be ready to go when they say so.

There is a ferry from Busan, Korea to Fukuoka, Japan but you have to get to Korea first and then travel to the coast so it will probably cost the same overall.

US$700 return is not bad, a good seat sale might get it down to $500.

However, given the daily cost of living in Japan, can you afford the rest of the trip? It's not somewhere you go for a cheap holiday, that's Thailand.

Comment: Cargo ships are usually very expensive for passengers but I'd love to hear about a budget priced one in this area. There are also ferries from Busan to Shimonoseki. Train travel in Korea is very cheap and quick. For experienced budget travellers it is absolutely possible to go to Japan for a cheap holiday. Not as cheap as Thailand but a lot cheaper than Australia. You have to know what you're doing though. But I agree with the conclusion that $700 may be hard to beat depending on season and special offers.

Answer (score 6):

The various Asian LCC (low-cost-carriers) airplane companies are the way to go. Check out Air Asia, Peach, Vanilla Air, etc. You should be able to travel for way less than US$300 return if you book at the right time.

For example, this flight from Hong Kong to Osaka one way is less than US$120 on Peach:
[image]

Similarly, this flight from Taipei to Tokyo one way is less than US$120:

[image]

Comment: i'd like to add more option: **JetStar** (included in etc., but wanted to clearly mention for readers)